# How to iterate over multiple imported modules from index file

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a directory called `Polygons` where I have created an `index.js` file to export all the files from the directory. It looks something like this:

```
export {default as europe} from './europe'
export {default as northAmerica} from './northAmerica'
```

`europe` file exports variable like this:

```
export default europe;
```

And in the file where I would like to use this variables I am importing them like this:

```
import * as regions from './Polygons'
```

I would like to iterate somehow now over those imports, is there any way of doing this?

I have tried doing:

```
  for (const element of regions) {
    console.log(element);
  }
```

But, then I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is an object, so for..of will fail but you can use `Object.keys` or `Object.values` to convert it into array and then get the results.

Here is a sample code which is doing the same:

```js
keys = Object.keys(React)
for (const key of keys) {
  console.log(key, React[key])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.